# Ruby rspec mocking a utility method

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

How does one mock a utility method that is located in a file referenced by

```
require 'myfile.rb'
```

The contents of the file are like so.

```
public
def my_method_name(arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
  ....
}
```

At the moment, I have something like:

```
double("mydouble", "my_method_name" => somehash)
```

I then unit test the class I am testing, which calls this method, but this does not seem to be mocking the method at all.
All help is appreciated

Basically, the method I want to mock does some network query. I want to just say: Anytime this method is called, return this hash. This method is not part of a class (or so I believe).

Comment: Do you want to stub the method for all instances of a class? Can you give a sample code with what you expected to happen?

Comment: Edited question above. The method I want to mock is used in the class I am testing. Not sure if that was clear by my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby all methods are associated to something (module or class). Methods that you define at the top level actually become private methods of `Kernel`.

---

```
x = double("mydouble", "my_method_name" => somehash)
```

Doesn't stub the method `my_method_name`. It creates a double (separate object). If you invoke `#my_method_name` on it, it will respond with `somehash`:

```
x.my_method_name # => somehash
```

---

Find the object the method is being invoked on. If it's easily replaced and doesn't have that much more functions, you can pass this double instead on it's place. If that is not the case, you can stub the method on that object by doing:

```
said_object.stub(my_method_name: somehash)
```

If you want to stub it for all instances of a class, you could do:

```
TheObjectsClass.any_instance.stub(my_method_name: somehash)
```

---

*Disclaimer:* The topic is a bit more complex and subject to debate. Don't consider this as a good testing practice, it just aims to help you understand how to use rspec.

---

You said this is related to networking. You can consider using [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to simulate actual requests.

Answer (score 0):

Since the class you are testing is the one on which this method is called, you should be stubbing the method on the same class

```
allow(<your_class_instance>).to receive(:my_method_name).and_return(<>)
```

I am assuming this method is an instance method. If its a class method, you will have to stub it at the class level